# How can I add a section reference to equation labels in an unnumbered section?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, equations, numbering

I have an unnumered section in a document, defining notation for the further contents. Since it's unnumbered, the equations within are labelled: '(1)', etc.

For example:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Notation}
\label{sec:notation}
A dot over any object denotes the time derivative of that object. Hence,\\
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}\alpha(x) = \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\alpha(x) = \frac{1}{c}\dot{\alpha}(x).
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

generates:

[image: MWE]

Is there a way I can tell latex to automatically label these as '(N.1)' similar to an appendix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In using an ordinary `equation` environment, you can prepend what you're interested in adding to the equation number by modifying `\theequation` - the printing mechanism for the `equation` counter. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A numbered section}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) =  ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqnA}
\end{equation}
See~(\ref{eqnA}).
\section*{An unnumbered section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{N.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) =  ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqnB}
\end{equation}
See~(\ref{eqnB}).
\end{document}
```

Note that you cannot update `\theequation` *inside* the `equation` environment, since the counter stepping (and reference *setting*) is done at the start of the environment. That is, it would be too late to update this inside `equation` for it to be picked up.

If the change should be temporary, you can either localize it using a group, or reset it manually where you want it to change.

---

If you're only after updating the *reference* and not the equation number itself, you could modify `\p@equation`, since the construction of `\@currentlabel` - the element that stored counters that are `\refstep`-ed - has the following form (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
```

Note how `\@currentlabel` is (roughly) defined as `\p@<cntr>\the<cntr>`.

Comment: A local `\renewcommand` for this section is exactly what I needed. Thanks.